# Create array X with certain number of copies of each element in array Y in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `counts = [2, 3, 4]` with each element denoted by `c`. I want to convert it into an array `weights` that has `m` copies of each element `c`, where `m` is an element in `M = [3, 2, 1]`.

So in the end, I'd like an array `weights = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]`

Is there an efficient way to do this in numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) does *exactly* what you want:

```
>>> np.repeat(counts, M)
array([2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4])
```